# Intel GPUs, issue with VBOs, and SFML

Tags: c++, opengl, cross-platform, intel, sfml

I'm developing a game using [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) and have recently learned that Intel GPUs do not support OpenGL VBOs.  This is a problem because SFML uses VBOs to render to surfaces that aren't the display window.

https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues/101

The information I've learned this from was dated by a few months, and the developer of SFML has said the issue was "possibly resolved" today, seemingly because someone said Intel updated their drivers to support VBOs.  (So it could very well remain broken, but I don't have an intel system to test that on)

**My question is**, is there still an issue with Intel GPUs and VBOs?  Is it a major issue that's going to limit my audience(Windows/Mac/Linux)?  And if that's the case, what is the best alternative to SFML?

**Edit**: The library writer fixed the issue yesterday.  Also, I mistook the issue at hand, it had nothing to do with VBOs.  I should've double checked my sources, sorry!  I think it was just an issue with ... a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a problem because SFML uses **VBOs** to **render to surfaces that aren't the display window**.

Wait, what?  Perhaps you're thinking of [Framebuffer Objects (FBOs)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object).

Heck, your [linked issue](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues/101) never even mentions VBOs.

Comment: The Linux drivers for Intel GPUs support FBOs just fine.

Comment: works great on mac with intel GPUs as well, FBOs are pretty fundamental to how Modern OpenGL is designed

Comment: Sorry... I misread and thought they were talking about VBOs.  Wrong BO!  And also, the library writer did fix it recently.  So... I guess I was flipping out for no reason!  Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

> recently learned that Intel GPUs do not support OpenGL VBOs

Then you've learned wrong. Buffer Objects are supported perfectly fine in Intel GPUs.

Comment: I did, sorry about that.  I should've double checked my source.  Or at least knew something as vital as VBOs would be fine.  I just panicked thinking half my code base was flawed, aha.

Answer (score 1):

VBOs are supported by very old intel cards already. They are also part of OpenGL 1.5 from 2003. It is no issue.